# AKKA remote (with SSL) can't find keystore/truststore files on classpath

Tags: scala, netty, akka, keystore

I'm trying to configure AKKA SSL connection to use my keystore and trustore files, and I want it to be able to find them on a classpath.

I tried to set application.conf to:

```
...
remote.netty.ssl = {
        enable = on
        key-store = "keystore"
        key-store-password = "passwd"
        trust-store = "truststore"
        trust-store-password = "passwd"
        protocol = "TLSv1"
        random-number-generator = "AES128CounterSecureRNG"
        enabled-algorithms = ["TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"]
    }
...
```

This works fine if `keystore` and `trustore` files are in the current directory. In my application these files get packaged into WAR and JAR archives, and because of that I'd like to read them from the classpath.

I tried to use `getResource("keystore")` in application.conf as described [here](https://github.com/typesafehub/config/blob/master/HOCON.md#include-semantics-locating-resources) without any luck. Config reads it literally as a string.

I also tried to parse String conf and force it to read the value:

```
val conf: Config = ConfigFactory parseString (s"""
...
"${getClass.getClassLoader.getResource("keystore").getPath}" 
...""")
```

In this case it finds proper path on the classpath as `file://some_dir/target/scala-2.10/server_2.10-1.1-one-jar.jar!/main/server_2.10-1.1.jar!/keystore` which is exactly where it's located (in the jar). However, underlying Netty SSL transport can't find the file given this path, and I get:

```
Oct 03, 2013 1:02:48 PM org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink
WARNING: Failed to initialize an accepted socket.
45a13eb9-6cb1-46a7-a789-e48da9997f0fakka.remote.RemoteTransportException: Server SSL connection could not be established because key store could not be loaded
    at akka.remote.netty.NettySSLSupport$.constructServerContext$1(NettySSLSupport.scala:113)
    at akka.remote.netty.NettySSLSupport$.initializeServerSSL(NettySSLSupport.scala:130)
    at akka.remote.netty.NettySSLSupport$.apply(NettySSLSupport.scala:27)
    at akka.remote.netty.NettyRemoteTransport$PipelineFactory$.defaultStack(NettyRemoteSupport.scala:74)
    at akka.remote.netty.NettyRemoteTransport$PipelineFactory$$anon$1.getPipeline(NettyRemoteSupport.scala:67)
    at akka.remote.netty.NettyRemoteTransport$PipelineFactory$$anon$1.getPipeline(NettyRemoteSupport.scala:67)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink$Boss.registerAcceptedChannel(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:277)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink$Boss.run(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:242)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/some_dir/server/target/scala-2.10/server_2.10-1.1-one-jar.jar!/main/server_2.10-1.1.jar!/keystore (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:97)
    at akka.remote.netty.NettySSLSupport$.constructServerContext$1(NettySSLSupport.scala:118)
    ... 10 more
```

I wonder if there is any way to configure this in AKKA without implementing custom SSL transport. Maybe I should configure Netty in the code?

Obviously I can hardcode the path or read it from an environment variable, but I would prefer a more flexible classpath solution.

I decided to look at the `akka.remote.netty.NettySSLSupport` at the code where exception is thrown from, and here is the code:

```
  def initializeServerSSL(settings: NettySettings, log: LoggingAdapter): SslHandler = {
log.debug("Server SSL is enabled, initialising ...")

def constructServerContext(settings: NettySettings, log: LoggingAdapter, keyStorePath: String, keyStorePassword: String, protocol: String): Option[SSLContext] =
  try {
    val rng = initializeCustomSecureRandom(settings.SSLRandomNumberGenerator, settings.SSLRandomSource, log)
    val factory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm)
    factory.init({
      val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType)
      val fin = new FileInputStream(keyStorePath)
      try keyStore.load(fin, keyStorePassword.toCharArray) finally fin.close()
      keyStore
    }, keyStorePassword.toCharArray)
    Option(SSLContext.getInstance(protocol)) map { ctx ⇒ ctx.init(factory.getKeyManagers, null, rng); ctx }
  } catch {
    case e: FileNotFoundException    ⇒ throw new RemoteTransportException("Server SSL connection could not be established because key store could not be loaded", e)
    case e: IOException              ⇒ throw new RemoteTransportException("Server SSL connection could not be established because: " + e.getMessage, e)
    case e: GeneralSecurityException ⇒ throw new RemoteTransportException("Server SSL connection could not be established because SSL context could not be constructed", e)
  }
```

It looks like it must be a plain filename (String) because that's what FileInputStream takes.

Any suggestions would be welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of writing this question there was no way to do it AFAIK. I'm closing this question but I welcome updates if new versions provide such functionality or if there are other ways to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I also got stuck in similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47366039/1610034) and was getting similar [errors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47349020/1610034). In my case I was trying to hit an https server with self-signed certificates using akka-http, with following code I was able to get through:

```
val trustStoreConfig = TrustStoreConfig(None, Some("/etc/Project/keystore/my.cer")).withStoreType("PEM")
val trustManagerConfig = TrustManagerConfig().withTrustStoreConfigs(List(trustStoreConfig))

val badSslConfig = AkkaSSLConfig().mapSettings(s => s.withLoose(s.loose
  .withAcceptAnyCertificate(true)
  .withDisableHostnameVerification(true)
).withTrustManagerConfig(trustManagerConfig))

val badCtx = Http().createClientHttpsContext(badSslConfig)

Http().superPool[RequestTracker](badCtx)(httpMat)
```