# How to make a POST call to self-certified server with akka-http

Tags: scala, ssl, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I have a akka-streams topology, where I make a POST call using akka-http.

I am getting following error when hitting the post request to a un-secure server(having self-signed certs). It is a internal server, so I am fine from security point of view.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1478) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:535) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:813) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:781) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at akka.stream.impl.io.TLSActor.akka$stream$impl$io$TLSActor$$doUnwrap(TLSActor.scala:367) ~[akka-stream_2.11-2.4.17.jar:?]
    at akka.stream.impl.io.TLSActor.akka$stream$impl$io$TLSActor$$doInbound(TLSActor.scala:290) ~[akka-stream_2.11-2.4.17.jar:?]
    at akka.stream.impl.io.TLSActor$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(TLSActor.scala:225) ~[akka-stream_2.11-2.4.17.jar:?]
    at akka.stream.impl.Pump$class.pump(Transfer.scala:199) ~[akka-stream_2.11-2.4.17.jar:?]
    at akka.stream.impl.io.TLSActor.pump(TLSActor.scala:48) ~[akka-stream_2.11-2.4.17.jar:?]
    at akka.stream.impl.BatchingInputBuffer.enqueueInputElement(ActorProcessor.scala:90) ~[akka-stream_2.11-2.4.17.jar:?]
    at akka.stream.impl.BatchingInputBuffer$$anonfun$upstreamRunning$1.applyOrElse(ActorProcessor.scala:141) ~[akka-stream_2.11-2.4.17.jar:?]
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36) ~[scala-library-2.11.8.jar:?]
    at akka.stream.impl.SubReceive.apply(Transfer.scala:16) ~[akka-stream_2.11-2.4.17.jar:?]
    at akka.stream.impl.FanIn$InputBunch$$anonfun$subreceive$1.applyOrElse(FanIn.scala:234) ~[akka-stream_2.11-2.4.17.jar:?]
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36) ~[scala-library-2.11.8.jar:?]
    at akka.stream.impl.SubReceive.apply(Transfer.scala:16) ~[akka-stream_2.11-2.4.17.jar:?]
    at akka.stream.impl.SubReceive.apply(Transfer.scala:12) ~[akka-stream_2.11-2.4.17.jar:?]
    at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123) ~[scala-library-2.11.8.jar:?]
    at akka.stream.impl.SubReceive.applyOrElse(Transfer.scala:12) ~[akka-stream_2.11-2.4.17.jar:?]
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:170) ~[scala-library-2.11.8.jar:?]
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:497) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.4.17.jar:?]
    at akka.stream.impl.io.TLSActor.aroundReceive(TLSActor.scala:48) ~[akka-stream_2.11-2.4.17.jar:?]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.4.17.jar:?]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.4.17.jar:?]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.4.17.jar:?]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.4.17.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1728) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:304) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1514) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1026) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:966) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:963) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1416) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at akka.stream.impl.io.TLSActor.runDelegatedTasks(TLSActor.scala:402) ~[akka-stream_2.11-2.4.17.jar:?]
    at akka.stream.impl.io.TLSActor.akka$stream$impl$io$TLSActor$$doUnwrap(TLSActor.scala:371) ~[akka-stream_2.11-2.4.17.jar:?]
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchIP(HostnameChecker.java:144) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:93) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:455) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:436) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:252) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:136) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1501) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1026) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:966) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:963) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1416) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at akka.stream.impl.io.TLSActor.runDelegatedTasks(TLSActor.scala:402) ~[akka-stream_2.11-2.4.17.jar:?]
    at akka.stream.impl.io.TLSActor.akka$stream$impl$io$TLSActor$$doUnwrap(TLSActor.scala:371) ~[akka-stream_2.11-2.4.17.jar:?]
```

Some discussion happened [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/akka-user/ziI1fPBtxV8), and another solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5871301/1610034) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15674540), but didn't worked for me and one unfinished discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/akka-user/SSLHandshakeException%7Csort:date/akka-user/6EU3Yeo22Mw/ifGqIpy5AwAJ). One solution is proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28787883/1610034) but not sure how to implement the same for akka-http.
Few more relevant links:

[akka-issue](https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/20381)

[Configuring Trust Stores](https://jonas.github.io/ssl-config/KeyStores.html#configuring-a-trust-manager)

[SO Question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41981320/scala-sbt-and-corporate-proxy-suncertpathbuilderexception)

[SO Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076179/pkix-path-building-failed-and-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requ)

[Solution in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19542614/1610034)

earlier I was using just following to execute it:

```
Http().superPool[MyTracker]()
```

I also tried following, getting inspiration from [here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.8/scala/http/client-side/client-https-support.html#clientsidehttps) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/akka-user/DjCQP28l52k), but problem persists:

```
    val badSslConfig = AkkaSSLConfig().mapSettings(s => s.withLoose(s.loose.withAcceptAnyCertificate(true)))
    val badCtx = Http().createClientHttpsContext(badSslConfig)
    Http().superPool[MyTracker]()(httpMat)
```

### Edit #1

I added one more flag, but got different error than earlier:

```
    val badSslConfig = AkkaSSLConfig().mapSettings(s => s.withLoose(s.loose.withAcceptAnyCertificate(true).withDisableHostnameVerification(true)))
    val badCtx = Http().createClientHttpsContext(badSslConfig)
    Http().superPool[MyTracker]()(httpMat)
```

Error:

```
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
```

### Edit #2

Getting inspiration from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28787883), not sure how to implement that with akka-httlp exactly, I tried following:

```
val trustStoreConfig = TrustStoreConfig(None, Some("/Users/user/path/my.cer")).withStoreType("PEM")
val trustManagerConfig = TrustManagerConfig().withTrustStoreConfigs(List(trustStoreConfig))

val sslConfig = AkkaSSLConfig().mapSettings { s =>
  s.withHostnameVerifierClass(classOf[DisabledComplainingHostnameVerifier])
  s.withTrustManagerConfig(trustManagerConfig)
  s
}
val badCtx = Http().createClientHttpsContext(sslConfig)
Http().superPool[RequestTracker](badCtx)(httpMat)
```

But still getting this error:

> Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
>
> at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchIP(HostnameChecker.java:144) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
>
> at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:93) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
>
> at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:455) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
>
> at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:436) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
>       at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:252) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
>
> at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:136) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
>
> at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1501) ~[?:1.8.0_131]

Is this not possible in Akka?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, Getting inspiration from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41770677/1610034), which seems way complicated, With following code snippet it worked:

```
val trustStoreConfig = TrustStoreConfig(None, Some("/etc/Project/keystore/my.cer")).withStoreType("PEM")
val trustManagerConfig = TrustManagerConfig().withTrustStoreConfigs(List(trustStoreConfig))

val badSslConfig = AkkaSSLConfig().mapSettings(s => s.withLoose(s.loose
  .withAcceptAnyCertificate(true)
  .withDisableHostnameVerification(true)
).withTrustManagerConfig(trustManagerConfig))

val badCtx = Http().createClientHttpsContext(badSslConfig)

Http().superPool[RequestTracker](badCtx)(httpMat)
```

Not sure why it did not work with other attempts of mine, will like to understand this deeply, Please post an explanation if you know the internals.

Comment: ... and if you have the key in a string, and not in a file, you can use  `TrustStoreConfig(Some(keyString), None)` instead

Comment: This is a super insecure solution disabling all security in HTTPS. But I agree it's somewhat hard to get right. We hope to publish better guides on for different TLS setups in the future.

Comment: @jrudolph, you are right, but I think methods like `withAcceptAnyCertificate` have been provided for such cases where we know and rely on the HTTP end-point.